# What Are The Disadvantages Of Using JPEG Image For Texturing

Tags: texturing

I'm new to texturing so I just wanted to know what the disadvantages are of just using JPEG image or taking a high resolution picture from your phone for texturing cloth , then adding bump or displacement nodes instead of buying textures from websites with colour maps and normal maps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you want to achieve.
Basically, JPEGs are not all bad, especially for photographed image textures they work just fine.

Typical disadvantages of the JPEG format are:

- Compression artifacts (should only be a problem if you have low quality or need very high detail)
- No transparency channel (can be a problem if you want multiple overlaid textures or stencils)
- Limited colordepth (for height- or bumpmaps or environment textures, the number of colors and/or brightness levels can be insufficient)

As advantages, I'd name the following:

- It's usually the most readily available format for images (if you take or download a photo in JPEG format, you won't gain anything by converting it into another format)
- For typical photographic images, it uses comparatively little space on your hard drive

Comment: For clothing textures such as T-shirt, jeans and coats. What would you recommend for this? I can’t find any website that has clothing textures

Comment: For those I'd say your idea with the photographed (or better: Do you have a flatbed scanner?) textures should work quite well. If you are not necessarily interested in super-detail, super-realism, you can even use the same texture for image and bump with pretty good results...

But I really doubt that there are no websites with clothing textures out there! (Hint: Try searching for "fabric" textures instead!)

Comment: Flatbed scanner? Would that give super realism and super detail? Flatbed scanners sold in everyday electronic stores?

Comment: A flatbed scanner (yes, even consumer-grade machines from any electronic store) gives you distortion-free images with homogeneous lighting. Using one instead of a camera may save you some cleanup-work with the textures. But before you buy one, maybe search again for "fabric textures" - you will find that quite a lot of people have done that work for you already. Unless want to do it yourself, then I'd go with the scanner...

Comment: Here are a couple of websites I use that offer CC0 (Free for all uses, no restrictions) licensed textures.
https://www.cgbookcase.com/textures?category=Fabric&resolution=1&page=1&color=all&search=
https://3dtextures.me/category/fabric/

Comment: Thanks guys! :)